# when i am running `service mysql status` it is reporting unrecognized service. should i install mysql server as well?

Tags: mysql

i have installed MYSQL for Python with the below command.
`sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`
but when i am running `service mysql status` it is reporting unrecognized service.
should i install mysql server as well?

i want to run mysql. so that i can install reviewboard. but it seems even after installing pythn-mysqldb as per the instruction, mysql is not running.

i am  following the instructions given https://www.reviewboard.org/get/instructions/?product=rb&org-type=opensource&contact-email=&support-level=&contact-last-name=&os=linux-deb&contact-first-name=&org-name=

Comment: "should i install mysql server as well?" What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to run mysql. so that i can install reviewboard. but it seems even after installing pythn-mysqldb as per the instruction, mysql is not running.

Comment: Which instructions? If you want to run a MySQL server, you'll have to install `mysql-server`.

Comment: below is the link for instruction.  https://www.reviewboard.org/get/instructions/?product=rb&org-type=opensource&contact-email=&support-level=&contact-last-name=&os=linux-deb&contact-first-name=&org-name=

Comment: @waltinator: I think your comment is actually the answer to this question.

Comment: @subhadip, welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you [edit] the question and add to it the information you mention in your comments. Please, read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

`python-mysqldb` helps your Python program access a MySQL server, anywhere on the network. If you want to access a MySQL server running on `localhost`, you will have to run a MySQL server, by installing and configuring `mysql-server`.

Comment: thanks alot. i have installed mysql server. this is working now. :)